# xltabular colors the table caption when using rowcolors

Tags: color, captions, xltabular

I'm creating a table using `rowscolor` from xcolor package, but the caption is treated as a row and it's colored. How to avoid this behavior ?

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{2}{blue!30}{}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| c | X |}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{blue!50}
        \textcolor{white}{\bf Ubicación temporal} & \textcolor{white}{\bf Evento} \\ \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{2}{|@{}r|}{\ldots\ \small Continúa en la siguiente página}\\\hline \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        % Table body%
         1912 & Se instaló la planta de bombeo más grande del mundo en Meadi, Egipto, la cual usaba concentradores de cilindro parabólico logrando hasta 37 a 45 kW continuamente por 5 horas diarias, fue detenida en 1915 por el inicio de la primera guerra mundial y el bajo precio de los combustibles fósiles \\\hline
         1928 & Pasteur reportó el uso de concentradores solares para desalinizar agua \\\hline
         1956 & Se empiezan a usar las células solares de silicio de manera comercial a pequeña escala \\\hline
         1958 & Se lanza el primer satélite que usaba energía solar (Vanguard I) \\\hline
         1960's & se popularizó la industria de los calentadores solares de agua residenciales \\\hline
         1974 & EE.UU. crea el NREL, laboratorio que fue fundamental para el desarrollo de la energía solar en años posteriores \\\hline
         1980's & Se ponen en funcionamiento las primeras torres solares de manera demostrativa trasladándose al campo industrial en el 2007 \\\hline
         1982 & Se construye el primer parque solar \\\hline
         1981 &  En España se probó un sistema de 500kW de la Agencia Internacional de Energía para generación eléctrica usando concentradores parabólicos en la plataforma solar de Almería. \\\hline
        1994 & El NREL desarrolla celdas fotovoltaicas con hasta un 30\% de eficiencia de conversión \\\hline
        \caption{Resumen del avance de la energía solar durante los siglos XX y XXI con base en [13],[14],[15],[16]}
        \label{table:historia-energia-solar}
    \end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

**Note:** don't worry, `[13],[14],[15],[16]` are generated by `\cites{}{}`

Comment: Normally, in a long table, the caption is in the `endhead` section of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- At long tables captions are normally on the top of table parts (see @Bernard's comment)
- with use of the `tabularray` package table code is simple and gives desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Resumen del avance de la energía solar durante los siglos XX y XXI con base en [13],[14],[15],[16]},
  label = {table:historia-energia-solar}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { c X[j] },
                  row{odd} = {bg=blue!30},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=blue!60, fg=white, m},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
{Ubicación\\ temporal}  
        &   Evento  \\ 
% Table body%
1912    & Se instaló la planta de bombeo más grande del mundo en Meadi, Egipto, la cual usaba concentradores de cilindro parabólico logrando hasta 37 a 45 kW continuamente por 5 horas diarias, fue detenida en 1915 por el inicio de la primera guerra mundial y el bajo precio de los combustibles fósiles \\
1928 & Pasteur reportó el uso de concentradores solares para desalinizar agua \\
1956 & Se empiezan a usar las células solares de silicio de manera comercial a pequeña escala \\
1958 & Se lanza el primer satélite que usaba energía solar (Vanguard I) \\
1960's & se popularizó la industria de los calentadores solares de agua residenciales \\
1974 & EE.UU. crea el NREL, laboratorio que fue fundamental para el desarrollo de la energía solar en años posteriores \\
1980's & Se ponen en funcionamiento las primeras torres solares de manera demostrativa trasladándose al campo industrial en el 2007 \\
1982 & Se construye el primer parque solar \\
1981 &  En España se probó un sistema de 500kW de la Agencia Internacional de Energía para generación eléctrica usando concentradores parabólicos en la plataforma solar de Almería. \\
1994 & El NREL desarrolla celdas fotovoltaicas con hasta un 30\% de eficiencia de conversión \\
% Table body (repeaatd}
1912    & Se instaló la planta de bombeo más grande del mundo en Meadi, Egipto, la cual usaba concentradores de cilindro parabólico logrando hasta 37 a 45 kW continuamente por 5 horas diarias, fue detenida en 1915 por el inicio de la primera guerra mundial y el bajo precio de los combustibles fósiles \\
1928 & Pasteur reportó el uso de concentradores solares para desalinizar agua \\
1956 & Se empiezan a usar las células solares de silicio de manera comercial a pequeña escala \\
1958 & Se lanza el primer satélite que usaba energía solar (Vanguard I) \\
1960's & se popularizó la industria de los calentadores solares de agua residenciales \\
1974 & EE.UU. crea el NREL, laboratorio que fue fundamental para el desarrollo de la energía solar en años posteriores \\
1980's & Se ponen en funcionamiento las primeras torres solares de manera demostrativa trasladándose al campo industrial en el 2007 \\
1982 & Se construye el primer parque solar \\
1981 &  En España se probó un sistema de 500kW de la Agencia Internacional de Energía para generación eléctrica usando concentradores parabólicos en la plataforma solar de Almería. \\
1994 & El NREL desarrolla celdas fotovoltaicas con hasta un 30\% de efiencia de conversión \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The caption package makes the caption stick out of the width of the table. Here is a changed version of the example with the caption package commented out:

```
        \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{2}{blue!30}{}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| c | X |}

       \caption{Resumen del avance de la energía solar durante los siglos XX y XXI con base en [13],[14],[15],[16] \label{table:historia-energia-solar}}\\%[\belowcaptionskip]

        \hline
        \rowcolor{blue!50}
        \textcolor{white}{\bf Ubicación temporal} & \textcolor{white}{\bf Evento} \\ \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{2}{|@{}r|}{\ldots\ \small Continúa en la siguiente página}\\\hline \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        % Table body%
         1912 & Se instaló la planta de bombeo más grande del mundo en Meadi, Egipto, la cual usaba concentradores de cilindro parabólico logrando hasta 37 a 45 kW continuamente por 5 horas diarias, fue detenida en 1915 por el inicio de la primera guerra mundial y el bajo precio de los combustibles fósiles \\\hline
         1928 & Pasteur reportó el uso de concentradores solares para desalinizar agua \\\hline
         1956 & Se empiezan a usar las células solares de silicio de manera comercial a pequeña escala \\\hline
         1958 & Se lanza el primer satélite que usaba energía solar (Vanguard I) \\\hline
         1960's & se popularizó la industria de los calentadores solares de agua residenciales \\\hline
         1974 & EE.UU. crea el NREL, laboratorio que fue fundamental para el desarrollo de la energía solar en años posteriores \\\hline
         1980's & Se ponen en funcionamiento las primeras torres solares de manera demostrativa trasladándose al campo industrial en el 2007 \\\hline
         1982 & Se construye el primer parque solar \\\hline
         1981 &  En España se probó un sistema de 500kW de la Agencia Internacional de Energía para generación eléctrica usando concentradores parabólicos en la plataforma solar de Almería. \\\hline
        1994 & El NREL desarrolla celdas fotovoltaicas con hasta un 30\% de eficiencia de conversión \\\hline

    \end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: xltabular with caption]